# When VS 2010 RC is going to be released?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, azure

I was looking to install the latest [Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5664019e-6860-4c33-9843-4eb40b297ab6&displaylang=en).  However, this version doesn't work with Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2.  They say that the latest version of Azure Tools & SDK will only work with VS 2008 and VS 2010 RC and that for VS 2010 Beta 2 I still need to install [November release](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6967FF37-813E-47C7-B987-889124B43ABD&displaylang=en).

I know that VS 2010 is going to be released on April 12th this year but does anyone knows when VS 2010 RC is coming out?

**EDIT: The full RTM version of Visual Studio 2010 is released as of April 14, 2010.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Scott Gu's blog, RC will be available sometime this month.

Source: [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/12/17/visual-studio-2010-and-net-4-0-update.aspx)

Comment: +1: That's the best you're going to get from a Microsoft employee answering the question directly.

Comment: +1 for a quick reply.  If nobody gives me a more precise answer, your reply will be accepted.

Comment: Wow! Thought there was a rumour back in December or thereabouts that it was going to be pushed back for more testing on the RC....the source of the rumour came from CodeProject's Lounge...can't say who, but I recall there was a conversation in the Lounge about it...

Comment: Here's an article from Visual Studio magazine that confirms that it's going to be released this month. http://bit.ly/agnZiH

Comment: Too bad it is not a leap year.

Answer (score 5):

[Visual Studio 2010 RC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd582936.aspx) is out today, February 8th, to MSDN subscribers.  Everybody else will get it on February 10th.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2010 has been [Released](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions).

Answer (score 0):

Few comments about RC from [scottgu](http://twitter.com/scottgu):

> string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() which checks for spaces, empty or null.
>
> Perf improvements with VS 2010 RC compared to previous builds are huge. Really happy with what I'm seeing so far.
>
> Oh my goodness, VS2010 RC is much, much faster. Kudos to VS perf team and everyone else.
>
> VS 2010 RC performance is ridiculously faster, can't wait to switch over full time!
>
> Trying out VS2010 RC: Snappier UI, much faster intellisense, significant build time reduction. Overall: AWESOME JOB!
>
> etc.

Answer (score 0):

Release starting Wednesday for non MSDN-ers

Source: [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/08/vs-2010-net-4-release-candidate.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, VS2010 RC is out, and is compatible with Windows Azure Tools 1.1, which was just released a short time ago.

However, be aware that Silverlight 4 is not supported in VS2010RC. Silverlight 3 is, however. Eventually Silverlight 4 support will return, but it will based on the Silverlight team pushing out an updated beta.